# Unable to call some functions on AngularFirestoreCollections with AngularFire and ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire2

I am experimenting with AngularFire and Ionic.  I am trying to follow along with a few tutorials I have found and am trying to model a service I am making based almost 100% off of the example found on the current [AngularFire example from their github.](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md) The problem that I am having is that anytime I make a collection, none of the methods such as .add(), where(), or snapshotChanges() seem to be working.  On my WebStorm IDE they are red saying that the methods are unresolved.

I am not sure whether this could be a versioning thing or if my imports are wrong or just maybe I am reading some wrong information.  I have seen quite a few example projects/tutorials and this particular pattern I am looking at seems quite common which is confusing to me.  Also I just deleted node modules and ran a fresh npm install.  If anyone could help me/point me in the right direction that would be great!  Thanks.

Here is some of the relevant files:

userservice.ts

```js
import {AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from '@angular/fire/firestore'
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import 'firebase/storage';
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import {map} from "rxjs/internal/operators";

/**
 * Created by Ben on 12/26/2018.
 */


export interface User {
  displayName: string;
}
export interface UserId extends User {
  id: string
}


@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  private usersCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection;
  private users: Observable<UserId[]>;

  constructor(public db: AngularFirestore) {
    this.usersCollection = db.collection('users');
    this.users = this.usersCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => {
        return actions.map(a => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data() as User;
          const id = a.payload.doc.id;
          return {id, ...data};
        })
      })
    )
  }

  saveUser(idToken: string, user: User) {
   return this.usersCollection.doc('idToken').add({
     displayName: user.displayName
   });
  }

  getUsersByDisplayName(displayName:string){
    return this.usersCollection.where("displayName", "===", displayName);
  }

}
```

app.module.ts

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from 'angularfire2/firestore';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import {FIREBASE_CONFIG} from "./app.firebase.config";
import {AuthService} from "../services/authservice";
import {HouseService} from "../services/houseservice";
import {UserService} from "../services/userservice";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(FIREBASE_CONFIG),
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AngularFirestoreModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    AuthService,
    HouseService,
    UserService,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

package.json

```js
{
  "name": "firebaseauth",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
    "@ionic-native/core": "~4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "~4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "~4.17.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.2.0",
    "angularfire2": "^5.1.1",
    "firebase": "^5.7.1",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "promise-polyfill": "^8.1.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.1",
    "typescript": "~2.6.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You found the right documentation, but it looks like you're getting a couple wires crossed. You are calling the `.add()` method on the wrong thing, it's supposed to be on the overall **collection**, and you are trying to use it on an individual **document**.

From [the link you gave](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md), notice this (*truncated*) code uses `.add()` on the **collection**:

```
constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.itemsCollection = afs.collection<Item>('items');
}
addItem(item: Item) {
    this.itemsCollection.add(item);
}
```

Where as you are trying on an individual **document**:

```
this.usersCollection.doc('idToken').add(
```

If you are trying to add a new document to this collection, just use `.add()` to the collection.

On the other hand, if you are trying to add details to an individual document, then check out [this documentation on AngularFire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md), as well as the [base Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) which shows you have `.set()`, `.update()`, `.get()`, and `.delete()` available for interacting with documents.

As to your problem with `.where()`...

You're also not using the correct syntax for the `where` clause, check out [this doc on querying collections](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/querying-collections.md) where they provide this example of the correct syntax:

```
afs.collection('items', ref => ref.where('size', '==', 'large'))
```

So yours should be:

```
return afs.collection('users', ref => ref.where('displayName', '==', displayName));
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem I was having is that my WebStorm IDE was 2 years out of date and was not recognizing a lot of the typescript typings.  I am posting this in the event that some lost soul in the same situation as I was will find this.  Thanks JeremyW for the answer though as it is correct!